# extending namespaces in another file

Tags: javascript

Im trying to extend a namespace methods/properties calling another files.
I have this:

main.js:

```
(function( ns, $, undefined ) {
    'use strict';
    ns.libs = {}
    ns.libsPath = "http://example.com/libs/";
    ns.foo = function foo(){
        return "Im a main Foo";
    }
    //Include file
    $.getScript(ns.libsPath+"super-foo.js");
}( window.ns = window.ns || {}, jQuery ));

console.log(ns.foo());//OK
console.log(ns.libs.superFoo());//FAIL
```

super-foo.js

```
console.log("File Loaded");
(function( ns, $, undefined ) {
    'use strict';
    ns.libs.superFoo = function(){
        return "Im a super Foo";
    }
}( window.ns = window.ns || {}, jQuery ));
console.log(ns.foo()); //OK
console.log(ns.libs.superFoo()); //OK
```

When i run the code i got something like this:

```
Im a main Foo //Ok
[Error in main.js method doesnt exists in ns]
File loaded 
Im a main Foo
Im a super Foo
```

The file was readed but doesnt extends main file namespace, only works in included file. Why this happens? How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was async in jquery to load script, replacing $.getScript for $.ajax fix the problem:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ns.libsPath+"super-foo.js",
    dataType: "script",
    async : false,
    success: function(){
        console.log("done");
    }
});
```